# batch script (.bat) called by openvpn process cannot successfully pass arguments to external .exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, openvpn

I have an openvpn server running on a windows 10 host. The openvpn server config has a parameter -auth-user-pass-verify which allows you to specify a script that will receive a login username and password in the form of a temporary file.

In the .bat file I capture the username and pass as follows

```
set /A count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%~1) do (
 if !count!==1 (
  set password=%%A
  set /A count=2
 )
 if !count!==0 (
  set username=%%A
  set /A count=1
 )
)
```

This part works and is verified, both when the script is run by myself and when it is called by openvpn. I then call an external .exe to verify the password.

```
for /f %%i in ('c:\"Program Files"\OpenVPN\config\foo\foo.exe %password%') do set RESULT=%%i
```

Now this last parts works when I call the .bat from command prompt myself, but it fails when the .bat is run by openvpn -- nothing is written to "RESULT". I don't even know if the exe is being called at all.

I have tried openvpn server with admin privileges. I have tried --script-security 2 and 3. Openvpn documentation says it calls the script "as a shell command" for what it's worth.

Comment: Sadly you obscured the path. Is it a relative one or an absolute one (does it start with a drive letter)? I guess only an absolute path will work.

Comment: I have tried both relative and absolute. I have updated the question to show its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f %%i in ('"c:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\foo\foo.exe" %password%') do set RESULT=%%i
```